# Construct a function $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ that takes every value in $[0,1]$ an infinite number of times.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I have a homework problem that I'm completely stumped on: Construct a function $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ that takes every value in $[0,1]$ an infinite number of times. I spent the better part of 2 hours on this problem, so I need some help. I started with a piece-wise function, just to get the every value an infinite number of times part, and played with it to make it continuous, but I made no progress. It's a very hard problem for me.

Comment: Toplogist's Sine Curve works:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve

Comment: There are good answers. Here is another approach: Construct a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ that oscillates between 0 and 1, then take the function $t \mapsto f(\tan {2 x \over \pi})$ on $[0,1)$ (define the function at $t=1$ any way you like).

Comment: Thank you for the two suggestions. They are both very instructive

Comment: You used the word "continuous" in the body of your question but not in the title. Do you want your function $f$ to be continuous, or you don't care? (I'm guessing you want it to be continuous.)

Comment: A continuous solution on a closed interval can't exist. Hint: accumulation points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want a function that oscillates "violently". Not sure if you have seen such wildly oscillating functions using $\sin$. If you have not seen it, the question is unfair as only a certified genius can come up with such examples *without any prior knowledge*. That said, here is very broad hint...
$$
f(x) = \sin(g(x))
$$
where you want $g(x)$ to grow to infinity in the interval. Then $f$ will have infinitely many oscillations. Now pick your favorite $g(x)$ that has a singularity in $[0,1]$

Comment: I think he wants a continuous function. Note the use of the word "continuous" in the body (though not in the title) of the question.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**: Draw a line connecting the points $(0,0)$ with $(1/2, 1)$. Draw a line connecting $(1/2,1)$ with $(3/4,0)$. Connect to $(7/8, 1)$.

Comment: That's not going to be a continuous function on $[0,1]$, is it?

Answer (score 6):

Here is an easy answer if you've seen how to construct a [space-filling curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve): just take a continuous mapping of the closed unit interval $[0,1]$ onto the closed unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, and follow it with a projection of the square onto its horizontal side. In other words, if $x=f(t),y=g(t),0\le t\le1$ is a parametric representation of a continuous curve which fills the unit square, then $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is a **continuous** function which takes every value in $[0,1]$ an **uncountable** number of times.

Comment: This is great lateral thinking!

Comment: Cool! And your criticism of my answer is very valid.